# как сделать, чтобы панель навигации при position: fixed занимала ширину родительского блока

Tags: css, fixed

как сделать, чтобы при positition: fixed сделать ширину навбара равной вмещающему блоку?
html:

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="nav">
          <div class="menu-btn">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-items">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#summary">Summary</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-items">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-items">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#education">Education</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-items">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#examples">Code examples</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-items">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#languages">Languages</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-items">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contacts">Contacts</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

СSS:

```
body {
    font: normal 16px/25px 'Times New Roman', 'Times', 'Georgia', serif;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 20px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #F0F5F9;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
}
.nav{
    background-color:rgb(173, 173, 241);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    position:fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu-btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 50px;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;

}

.menu-btn span {
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #222222;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.menu-btn span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.menu-btn span:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: calc(50% + 10px);
}

.menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
  }
.menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);  
  }
.menu-btn.active span:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(-45deg); 
  }

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav-list.active {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgb(173, 173, 241);
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-right: none;
    
}
.nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-items{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
.nav-link{
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
.nav-link:hover{
    color: #424874;
}
```

Получается, что панель выходит за пределы блока с классом  `.container`

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но на вскидку - у класса контейнера нет явно объявленной ширины. соответственно она устанавливается автоматически по заполненному контенту внутри, но ограничена body, но элементы внутри контейнера чхали на body, он им не прямой родитель... на выходе получаем проблемы с размерами

Comment: ```body {
    max-width: 1200px;} ```  у контейнера margin: 0 20px;,поэтому ширина контейнера будет ширина 1200-40;Пробовал задать явный размер контейнеру - не вышло, навбар выходит из общего потока и прикрепляется к верхнему правому края экрана. Я думаю, нужно сделать чтобы ширина навбара была равна ширине контейнера, но как сделать чтобы этот вариант был адаптивен-не пойму

Comment: возможно ли сделать это через js?```function widthNav (){
    const cont = document.querySelector('.container');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
    cont.style.width = nav.style.width;
}``` что-то вроде этого, и как то чтобы функция автоматически запускалась. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Я вот копаюсь в ваше коде, и не могу немного понять, а зачем вам это? Убрав фиксацию позиции, он спокойно встает туда куда нужно, и я могу с легкостью манипулировать контейнером как мне угодно

Comment: можно попробовать с position: fixed; просто в наглую у nav наследовать width: inherit;

Comment: я хочу, чтобы при прокрутке навбар оставался вверху

Comment: в наглую у nav наследовать width: inherit; тоже не получается, nav все равно выхватывается из потока и ширина не соответствует контейнеру

Comment: Я честно до сих пор не понимаю что конкретно вы хотите сделать, надеюсь ответ ниже я дал

Comment: ``` <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-items">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#summary">Summary</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-items">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- другое содержимое, навбар перестает перемещаться-->
    </div>``` навбар перемещается только до границы контейнера, но не до конца страницы

Comment: А зачем вам использовать два одинаковых контейнера? Это и создает резонанс, вы объявляете параметр на контейнер и в него же упираетесь

Answer (score 1):

Изменил только пару параметров в css - в итоге имеем, меню по центру, с шириной макс `1200px`, при прокрутке, нав бар буд-то приклеен к верху.
Делается это с помощью `position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 0;`

```
body {
  font: normal 16px/25px 'Times New Roman', 'Times', 'Georgia', serif;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container{  
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #F0F5F9;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}
.nav{
  
  background-color:rgb(173, 173, 241);
  width: inherit;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.menu-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;

}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-items{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.nav-link{
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.nav-link:hover{
  color: #424874;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какие-то параметры убрал, чтоб код не был большим

Comment: я со sticky тоже пробовал, но есть одна проблема. контейнер идет грубо говоря как строительная единица с содержащимися внутри него разделами. со sticky навбар перемещается, но только до границ контейнера, дальше, когда начинается другой контейнер навбар не перемещается

Comment: Я создал ещё один контейнер, дал ему класс, задал ширины и высоты, и все отлично работает.

Comment: так,  почему  у меня не фурычит

Comment: Скопируйте полностью мой css код вставьте себе, и от этого попробуйте оттолкнуться

Comment: да в том-то и дело, что фурычит, но только до границы блока. но эти блоки у меня в разных секциях, может в этом дело?

Comment: вот сыль:https://medium.com/web-standards/sticky-bc7ff7088693
а мое предположение в следующем посмотрите на контейнере z-index и выставите его -999. Может вам кажется что sticky не работает, а на самом деле он просто теряется за другим блоком

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось